# Cardinality of an open dense set in a compact Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal and let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space of size $2^\kappa$. Let $U$ be a dense open subset of $X$. Can you give a lower bound for the cardinality of $U$.  $2^\kappa$? $\kappa$?

Comment: Oops, I didn't see the words "compact Hausdorff." Now that I think of it, there are easy examples of dense open subsets of cardinality 1 when $X$ is not Hausdorff and has arbitrary cardinality.

Answer (score 4):

If $D_\kappa$ is the discrete space of cardinality $\kappa$, $\beta D_\kappa$ is a compact Hausdorff space of cardinality $2^{2^\kappa}$ in which $D_\kappa$ is a dense open set of cardinality $\kappa$. Thus, even $\kappa$ is too big to be a lower bound when $|X|=2^\kappa$.

This example is a worst case, though, since a regular space with with density $\kappa$ has cardinality at most $2^{2^\kappa}$.

Comment: Of course! So neither of my guesses is correct. The space I am working with is much nicer than $\beta D$, so maybe I can use the other properties... in particular $X$ is connected.

Comment: $\beta \mathbb{R}$ is also connected and is separable and has the same size as $\beta \mathbb{N}$